# label encode date

Tags: r, data-transformation, labeling

I am working in R. I want to set initial date(6-2018) as 0 and last date as(12-2020) whatever the last value is. I have around 19 unique dates. I tried to Label encode them but it changes to 0,1,1,1,1,17,18.. even for unique dates it is showing 0,0,0.
I checked frequency for 0 alotted variable that is 6-2018 there is only one frequency.
[image]